# How to manage existing resource group in azure with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am having my azure infrastructure created using terraform.

Now I want to add few resources to existing resource group.

When I did same it is giving error like resources group is already exists.

How can I refer existing resource and no changes to existing resources and tfstate file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways to refer existing resource in Azure without making changes.

- Use [Terraform import](https://www.terraform.io/cli/import)
- Use [Terraform data resource](https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources)

**Terraform import example**:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
    # ...instance configuration...
    name = "MyResourceGroup"    
}
```

Run command: `terraform import azurerm_resource_group.example \ /subscriptions/MySubscriptionNumber/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup`

**Terraform data resource example**:

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "MyResourceGroup"
}
```

Comment: If I use import do i need to import every resource like storage, data factory etc.  And when I am using data it shows it is not declared in root module.

Comment: terraform import command imports only one resource. You can import Azure resources into Terraform state that are already exist

Comment: I do not know your Terraform module structure but error "... not declared in root module" says that you need to declare data resource in root module

Comment: I don't have any module. I am directly in the root

Comment: Could you please share you error